# Reference ResourceDictionary by key and use it as window/control resource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

Is it possible to reference "nested" `ResourceDictionary` by `x:Key` instead of relative path?

**App.xaml**

```
<Application>
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="MyConstants" Source="Foo/Bar/MyConstants.xaml"/>

            <!-- other stuff -->

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window.Resources>

    <ResourceDictionary KeyReference="MyConstants"/>

</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: If the resource is already referenced in your 'Application.Resources' then there is no need to reference it in other locations as you will have access to it throughout the application.

Comment: @Nkosi That's not true. One can **merge** an external `ResourceDictionary` in `Application.Resources` and access its elements globally but I didn't do that here (note that there's no `ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries` wrap).

Comment: But isn't the elements what you want access to? Is there a constraint to using **merge**?

Comment: I do want to access the elements, but only when `MyConstants` dictionary is referenced (by key) in control's (or window's) `XYZ.Resources` scope.

Comment: I guess I don't understand your requirements. My bad.